# Part of Lines Missing when added to R Histogram Plot

Tags: r

Part of lines are missing when added into a R histogram.  I've played around with the inner and outer margins `par(mar=c(x,y,z,v)` and `par(oma=c(x,y,z,v)`, where x,y,z,v are numbers which correspond to margin values.  Doesn't seem to be a margin issue.  See the attached screen shot here:

[image]

Comment: [how to make a great r reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LoganWood If you first use `hist` and then `density`, try to increase `ylim` inside `hist`.